# QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED is only available in ios 8 or not

Tags: swift

I am using following code to download images in background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
   //code for image download
}
```

but getting error **“QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED is only available in ios 8  or not”**

Comment: Short answer: set you deployment target to iOS 8 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
```

}

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of the code in your question.

Comment: I just want to download images in background, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this relates to the fact that, of late, Apple has been encouraging developers to switch where possible (and appropriate) from using dispatch_queue_t and moving to the higher-level OperationQueue class.

As I'm sure you know, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED is a quality of service setting that you attach to a dispatch queue when the user has initiated a change and therefore the actions related to it need to be dispatched with high priority. The equivalent with an OperationQueue is to set the QualityOfService variable:

```
myOperationQueue.qualityOfService = QualityOfService.userInitiated
```

Take a look at the OperationQueue reference:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue

And the following article, which outlines how you can implement quality of service within the dispatch_queue framework:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html